# Replace single quote in insert query

Tags: objective-c

I am working in SQLite database for Iphone App.In Objecitve my following query is getting failed because of the value "This is user's profile" as it contains single quote.

INSERT INTO TEST(Code,Desc) VALUES('Test','This is user's profile')

Because of the String my insert query is going failed.

Please suggest a solution

Thanks,
Shradha harne

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, to escape single quotes you have to add an other single quite 'This is a user''s profile'

Answer (score 0):

Replace occurrence of **'** with **''** in your string and pass the value to your query, 
i.e. INSERT INTO TEST(Code,Desc) VALUES('Test','This is **user''s** profile')

Answer (score 0):

You could try to double the apostrophe sign in your text (i.e. '' instead of ').